# declaring New instance of WordprocessingDocument using OpenXML

Tags: .net, vb.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am attempting to use open XML for the first time. I am following a tutorial found here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36694/Creation-of-a-Word-2007-document-using-the-Open-XM. When I declare a variable as new `WordprocessingDocument` I receive the error:

> "Type WordprocessingDocument.Create is undefined".

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging

Partial Class test

Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    makedoc("file.docx")
End Sub

Private Sub makedoc(ByVal documentfilename As String)
    Using mydoc As New WordprocessingDocument.Create(documentfilename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
        Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = mydoc.AddMainDocumentPart()
        'Create Document tree for simple document. 
        mainPart.Document = New Document()
        'Create Body (this element contains
        'other elements that we want to include 
        Dim body As New Body()
        'Create paragraph 
        Dim paragraph As New Paragraph()
        Dim run_paragraph As New Run()
        ' we want to put that text into the output document 
        Dim text_paragraph As New Text("Hello World!")
        'Append elements appropriately. 
        run_paragraph.Append(text_paragraph)
        paragraph.Append(run_paragraph)
        body.Append(paragraph)
        mainPart.Document.Append(body)
        ' Save changes to the main document part. 
        mainPart.Document.Save()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a new instance of `WordDocumentProcessing` like this. The constructor is protected.

You need to call the `Create` or `Open` method :

```
Using mydoc as WordProcessingDocument = WordProcessingDocument.Create(DocumentFileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
   ...
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for the respone. I am fairly sure I was originally calling the Create method and removed it after getting the error just to see what happened without it. I will add it back just to be sure and let you know what the result is.

Comment: when I use .create I get an error that WordprocessingDocument.Create is not defined. Is there another class I need to import?

Comment: No, only the three class you mentioned above are required. This code works for me. I don't understand what happening for you.

Comment: Me either, Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I edited the question to show the actual code. Sorry about the error regarding the use of .Create earlier.

Comment: `Dim mydoc As WordprocessingDocument`
`mydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(documentfilename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)`
`Using mydoc`

Comment: Hopefully the last comment makes sense, mini-Markdown is not cooperating but that seems to have fixed the problem. I'll mark your answer as accepted since your first response was correct given the way I originally asked the question. Thanks again.